# Do I retain my rank and stats across platforms in Battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

I have been playing BF3 on my Xbox since it came out, and am now thinking about buying the PC version so I can play it on my laptop when I'm not at home.

I am aware that my game stats are kept with EA, so am I right in thinking that if I play BF3 on the PC (or PS3 for that matter), it will retain my rank and stats providing I log in with the same EA Origin account?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, your stats do not carry over platforms.
I can't find an official word from DICE, but I know they don't from experience.

I wish they did, I just built a PC and I'm rank 45 on the 360 :(

Comment: oh well, looks like i will be sticking with my 360 copy then! thanks

Comment: Yeah thats what I did to, I mean the PC version is great and all but its not worth re-ranking up again.

Answer (score 2):

@Emerica is correct: No they do not carry over platforms.  If you visit BF3's [Battlelog](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/gate/) and after you login, you will notice next to the player's origin name, which platform he/she is playing on with that account: PS3/XBOX360/PC.  You can link origin accounts but you cannot carry over earned rank from one platform to the other.